# Can a virus stay in a computer even after a reinstallation?

Tags: windows-8, virus

In the windows 8 system, there is a windows re-installation built in. It says "Remove everything and reinstall Windows". But, the computer needs to have somewhere to store windows itself in order for it to reinstall itself. So, my question it this: If a virus were to have full control of one's computer and the virus was to enter the area where the default windows re-installation storage is, is it possible for a virus to remain in one's computer even after a re-installation?

Comment: viruses, no, but other kinds of malware, certainly. more importantly, it sounds like you want to use on disk recovery. that isn't a good idea. install off disks that the malware can't reside in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is quite possible, if the manufacturer hasn't made any effort to cryptographically sign the recovery software.

Also, Master Boot Records can also have viruses, and MBR isn't always overwritten with reinstallation. So, a virus could persist that way too.